# How to fix list tail with match recursion? [Scala]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

This function is taking list and one of two functions below and have to match every element in list.

```
val sqrt = (x: Double) => x * x
val doubleValue = (x: Double) => 2 * x

val yoman = (list: List[Double], func: Function[Double, Double]) => list match {
  case head :: tail => func(head) :: yoman(tail, func)
  case Nil => list
}

yoman(List(3.0, 4.0, 99.0), sqrt)
yoman(List(-5.0, 1.0, 9.0), doubleValue)
```

Now I have a problem with first case:

```
Error:(5, 39) recursive lazy value yoman needs type
  case head :: tail => func(head) :: yoman(tail, func)
                                     ^
```

Comment: Why is `yoman` a val containing a lambda instead of a `def`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for recursive functions you need to specify the return type

```
  val yoman: (List[Double], Function[Double, Double]) => List[Double] = (list: List[Double], func: Function[Double, Double]) => list match {
    case head :: tail => func(head) :: yoman(tail, func)
    case Nil => list
  }
```

as you can see, you declare `yoman`, followed by the type (function that received a list and another function, and returns a list double), and then the body itself